# PHP creating .nfs00000 files?

Tags: php, nfs

I have a PHP app, which is working fine for me, both on test system and a production system.

But another user of my app wrote me, that it creates a lot of files .nfs00000* on his system and it slows down loading of the page.

My app does not create any files on the filesystem, all datas are stored into MySQL. So I was really surprised by this. But that user removed my PHP app from his website and the problem dissappeared.

I will be honest -- I know nothing about .nfs00000* files and I was not able to google out anything reasonable about them. Can someone please try to give me explanation, what they are, why they are created and if I can do anything to avoid their creation?

Thanx, Honza

Comment: [SF:SE already has a question on this.](http://serverfault.com/questions/201294/nfsxxxx-files-appearing-what-are-those)

Comment: seems to be some kind of log files. Have the user check whats the content of the file. maybe something needed by the app is missing on his computer

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/348137

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

> Under linux/unix, if you remove a file that a currently running process still has open, the file isn't really removed. Once the process closes the file, the OS then removes the file handle and frees up the disk blocks. This process is complicated slightly when the file that is open and removed is on an NFS mounted filesystem. Since the process that has the file open is running on one machine (such as a workstation in your office or lab) and the files are on the file server, there has to be some way for the two machines to communicate information about this file. The way NFS does this is with the .nfsNNNN files. If you try to remove one of these file, and the file is still open, it will just reappear with a different number. So, in order to remove the file completely you must kill the process that has it open.
>
> If you want to know what process has this file open, you can use 'lsof .nfs1234'. Note, however, this will only work on the machine where the processes that has the file open is running. So, if your process is running on one machine (eg. bobac) and you run the lsof on some other burrow machine (eg. silo or prairiedog), you won't see anything.

([Source](https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=123962105))

If your app is deleting or modifying some files it could be the cause of the problem.